# Battery charging circuit barely charges

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

The circuit in the picture is designed to charge a Li-po battery from USB.

The [MCP73832T-2DFI/OT](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf) datasheet says that a PROG resistor of 10 kΩ should charge at around 100 mA. When initially powered up the current draw was around 26 mA, VBAT was around 3.97 V. After about an hour, VBAT is up to 4.0 V and it's drawing about 14 mA, so the battery voltage is rising, but very slowly.

My understanding of the datasheet is that the current should be around 100 mA until VBAT gets close to 4.2 V.

The STAT pin is low, indicating that charging is happening.

VUSB is 4.9132 V, VIN when USB is connected is 4.6776 V, so the diode drop is 235 mV which is reasonable and lines up with the datasheet.

TVS diode D2 is not fitted.

The P channel MOSFET is a [DMP3099L](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP3099L.pdf)

Can anyone see anything obviously wrong here?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Consider what happens when the USB is connected and the LiPo battery is nearly depleted - e.g. at 3.0 volts. The 5 volts pass thru D1, then thru Q1's body diode, straight into the battery. The charging current would be nearly unlimited - it will depend on how stiff the USB supply is and may trigger fuses.

Comment: Aha, my mosfet is back to front! Thanks!

Comment: Your schematic symbol doesn't have a pin associated with the MCP73832's "EP" (Exposed thermal Pad) pin which, according to the datasheet, needs to be connected to Vss. Have you connected that pad?

Comment: I'm using the SOT23-5 which doesn't have the EP